# Search for timestamp anomalies in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, lubridate

im working with some GTFS data from Berlin and I am hitting a wall here right now.

There is a stop_times.txt file for all Busstops in Berlin with 5 million rows.
Two Columns (Arrival_time and Departure_time) contain anomalies, such as

Arrival_time : 112:30:0 instead of the regular format 11:20:30.

I dont really know how to extract those specific lines and erase them from the dataset. I cant come up with an algorithm which is able to detect it. I tried to go with the length of strings (should be 8  00:00:00 = 8 characters), but the errored ones are also 8 long.

Do you know a simple way to make sure that the format is always xx:xx:xx and delete all others?

Thanks...

Edit :

So, now after trying the below suggested solution, it didnt work because it would just tell me how many rows were malicious and not where and not how i could delete those.

My idea is basically now :

1. Find every timestamp which does not correspond to this exact format :

'00:00:00', where it has to be length '8' and 2 digits seperated by ':'. Is there a way to detect anomalies within this pattern and then delete them? I really dont know how to fix this issue anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` is such a useful package I can't remember how I was doing without it.

```
require(lubridate)
times <- c("112:30:0", "11:20:30")
datetimes <- paste("01.01.2018", times)
parsed.datetimes <- lubridate::dmy_hms(datetimes)
#[1] NA                        "2018-01-01 11:20:30 UTC"
#Warning message:
# 1 failed to parse.
```

This function will automatically tell you when format parsing failed, only thing is, it is taking datetime format as input instead of just times, but you can easily get around that like shown.

In order to know exactly which ones have failed to parse, you can then apply:

```
failed.list <- which(is.na(parsed.datetimes))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but i need to know which ones in the list of 5 millionen rows are flawed! It only showed me 93941 failed to parse